# Want the result to be displayed on the form

Tags: java, swing

I want the result to be displayed on the form.

Why is this code not working?

```
package Swing1_1;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class Swing2 {
       public static void main(String args[])
        {
           Addition obj=new Addition();
            obj.setVisible(true);
       }
    }
     class Addition extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
    {
        JTextField t1,t2;
        JLabel lbl;
        JButton b1;
       public Addition()
       {
            JTextField t1=new JTextField(20);
            JTextField t2=new JTextField(20);
            JLabel lbl=new JLabel("Result");
            JButton b1=new JButton("OKey");
             add(t1);
           add(t2);
            add(b1);
            add(lbl);
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
             //setVisible(true);
           setSize(400,400);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          b1.addActionListener(this);// 
         }

     public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae) 
           {
              int num1,num2,value;
               num1=Integer.parseInt("12");
               num2=Integer.parseInt("20");

            value=num1+num2;
              //System.out.println(value +"");
            lbl.setText(value +"");
        }
     }
```

Comment: Please read the online help regarding how to ask a good question and how to format code in questions.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is code. Looks like a big pile of characters to me. Do you mind fixing the formatting?

Comment: Add some more description, like if anything is displayed or not with this code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: Try removing `JLabel lbl=new JLabel("Result");` in `Addition()` constructor and replacing `JLabel lbl;` with `final JLabel lbl=new JLabel("Result");`.

Comment: @ErandikaHarshani thanks it worked

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your implementation is you declared `lbl`[1] variable as an `instance` variable in `Addition` class and in the `constructor` you again declared new variable `lbl`[2](same name) as `local` variable and instantiated. In `actionPerformed` method, you reset the value of `lbl` variable but here it is trying to reset the value of `lbl`[1]. Therefore it is throwing an exception because we cannot reset the value to reference type variable without instantiating. So the code should be following this;

```
class Addition extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextField t1, t2;
    JLabel lbl;
    JButton b1;

    public Addition() {
        JTextField t1 = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField t2 = new JTextField(20);
        lbl = new JLabel("Result");
        JButton b1 = new JButton("OKey");
        add(t1);
        add(t2);
        add(b1);
        add(lbl);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        // setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b1.addActionListener(this);//
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        int num1, num2, value;
        num1 = Integer.parseInt("12");
        num2 = Integer.parseInt("20");

        value = num1 + num2;
        // System.out.println(value +"");
        lbl.setText(value + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @AndrewThompson ! :)